# SQL function to run a counter that increases when a flag changes?

Tags: sql, db2, counter, window-functions, cycle

I have data that looks like the first three columns, and I'd like to add the fourth column for Cycle, which is null when the Flag is zero, and otherwise counts the occurrence of that flag for a given x, ordered by the date. I'm using db2 and I'm not sure how to modify a row_number() function to get this result.

```
  name  date           Flag        Cycle
    x     2014            0          Null
    x     2015            0          Null
    x     2016            1          1
    x     2017            1          1
    x     2018            0          Null
    x     2019            1          2
    x     2020            0          Null
    x     2021            1          3 
    y     2014            0          Null
    y     2016            1          1
    y     2017            0          Null
    y     2018            1          2
```

I'm looking for something that behaves like the Rank function, but allows a tie-ranking based on the duplicates in the partition statement and not the order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and a window `sum()`:

```
select
    name,
    date,
    flag,
    case when flag = 1 
        then sum(cycle_start) over(partition by name order by date) 
    end cycle 
from (
    select
        t.*,
        case
            when lag(flag) over(partition by name order by date) = 0 and flag = 1
            then 1
        end cycle_start
    from mytable t
) t
order by name, date
```

The inner query detects the cycle beginnings as transitions from `0` to `1`. The outer query does a window sum of the cycle starts and displays it only when the flag is on.

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=f8856a170ac96ebbd0ef83880085ba15)**:

```
NAME | DATE | FLAG | CYCLE
---: | ---: | ---: | ----:
   x | 2014 |    0 |  null
   x | 2015 |    0 |  null
   x | 2016 |    1 |     1
   x | 2017 |    1 |     1
   x | 2018 |    0 |  null
   x | 2019 |    1 |     2
   x | 2020 |    0 |  null
   x | 2021 |    1 |     3
   y | 2014 |    0 |  null
   y | 2016 |    1 |     1
   y | 2017 |    0 |  null
   y | 2018 |    1 |     2
```

Comment: This gets me closer to where I want to be, but I'm looking to make that 2016 for Y set to cycle 1, since the flag right before it is also 1. Currently it sets to null.

Comment: @Ara: that's a tiny change in the query (and your sample data changed too). Fixed!

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       (case when flag = 1
             then sum(flag) over (partition by name order by date)
        end) as cycle_start
from t;
```

This assumes that the flag only takes on the values `0` and `1`, as in the sample data.  It can easily be modified if the flag takes on other non-`0` values.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, I misunderstood the problem.  You want to identify the adjacent "groups" of records.  For that, define a group using the number of previous `NULL` values and then do a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       (case when flag = 1
             then dense_rank() over (partition by name order by grp)
        end) as cycle_start
from (select t.*,
             sum(1 - flag) over (partition by name order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Intended to suggest the same approach, you (as always) beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for! I'm looking for a solution that would assign rows next to eachother with the same flag to the same cycle.

Comment: @Ara . . . I misunderstood.  I updated the answer with an alternative version.